# Remember Form Input in .Net Core

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am currently working on a website that is working with over a 1000 records. each record needs an input field where the user can fill in the amount he wants of the product.
I have tried searching around but most of the 'answers' are PHP related or do not apply to me as they have a unique Id to the Input.

```cs
@foreach(var listItem in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@listItem.Name</td>
        <td>@listItem.Brand</td>
        <td>@listItem.Weight</td>
        <td>@listItem.Country</td>
        <td>@listItem.Price</td>
        <td>
             <form method="post"  asp-action="AddToCart">
                 <input type="hidden" name="ColumnNr" value="@listitem.ColumnNr" />
                 <input type="hidden" name="ColumnFollowUpNr" value="@listitem.ColumnFollowUpNr" />
                 <input type="hidden" name="sortingItem" value="@listitem.MainCategory" />
                 <input id="myInput" type="number" name="Amount" value="" onchange="this.form.submit();"/>
             </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

My AddToCart Methods puts the ColumnNr, the ColumnFollowUpNr and the amount in a Session Cookie that can be picked up anywhere on the website. I use these in another controller to create the list for the items for the shopping cart.

```cs
        public IActionResult AddToCart(short ColumnNr, short ColumnFollowUpNr, string sortingItem, int Amount)
        {
            var LoggedUser = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name);
            var amount = Amount;

            List<OrderItem> cart = new List<OrderItem>();
            string cartString = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Jager.Items");
            if (cartString != null)
            {
                //if cart exists --> deserialize. if OrderItem exists --> edit Amount. Else create new OrderItem
                cart = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OrderItem>>(cartString);
                var result = cart.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ColumnNr == ColumnNr && x.ColumnFollowUpNr == ColumnFollowUpNr );
                if (result != null)
                {
                    //only edits the amount if the OrderItem already exists
                    result.Amount = Amount;
                }
                else {
                    OrderItem order = new OrderItem
                    {
                        Id = ColumnNr + ColumnFollowUpNr ,
                        CurrentUser = LoggedUser,

                        Amount = Amount,
                        ColumnNr = ColumnNr,
                        ColumnFollowUpNr = ColumnFollowUpNr 

                    };
                    cart.Add(order);
                }
            }

            else {
                OrderItem order = new OrderItem
                {
                    Id = ColumnNr + ColumnFollowUpNr ,
                    CurrentUser = LoggedUser,

                    Amount = Amount,
                    ColumnNr = ColumnNr ,
                    ColumnFollowUpNr = ColumnFollowUpNr 
                };
                cart.Add(order);
            }

            cartString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cart);
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("Jager.Items", cartString);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { item = sortingItem.Trim() });
        }
```

The issue right now is: I want to remember the users input and upon activating the Method/Refreshing the website. It needs to remember the input on that specific column. I think I will need to use JavaScript or JQuery in order to get the `Amount` from the Cookie (which is named Jager.Items) and put that back into the designated column, but I wouldn't know how to, because none of my inputs have a unique id.

Any help is more than welcome as I am very new to JQuery and have little experience with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add a property `Amount` to the `@listItem`. In your Index action, you can get the amount from session and assign it to the Amount property. Then, in the index page, you can get the amount. Which like the shopping cart workflow.

```
<input id="myInput" type="number" name="Amount" value="@listItem.Amount" onchange="this.form.submit();"/>
```

Comment: I think I executed what you told me to do. Because the products that are being displayed are coming from a Database where I cannot alter any information, I had to add a copy of that table and add a property ``Amount`` to it. I am currently using the copy to display all my items (including the amount). Thank you for your help!